# Custom UitableView not working in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am newbie to ios development and i am just learning tableview with custom table cell,I used storyboard for making ui elements and for the custom cell i have made an xib file,I have referred.[Custom tableview i ios](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)

I have gone every steps but i dont know what is missing,i am getting following error.

```
2015-12-03 16:52:48.336 MyFirstApp[4997:176795] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<netcluesvideosViewController 0x7a05a6b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nameLabel.'
```

I am posting my code please help,

**net.h**

## import

```
@interface netcluesvideosViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
   NSArray *tabledata;
     IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
}
@end
```

**net.m**

```
.
.
.
.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"NetCell";

    NetCell *cell = (NetCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NetCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

.
.
.
.
```

NetCell is my custom cell class.

Comment: Post the screen shot of your storyboard and why are you creating .xib file. The standard practise is to create UI in storyboards now. Try these tutorials- http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard/

Comment: You had beforeHand a var name `nameLabel` in `netcluesvideosViewController`. Open the `netcluesvideosViewController` (StoryBoard or Xib), and check its outlets. Delete the one named `nameLabel`.

Comment: @natasha-Thanks for reply,but i just started learning and i really dont know whats rite and whats wrong..!!!

Comment: @Larme-thank you ,let me try tis one.

Comment: Just search "nameLabel" on Find navigatior in xcode and are you able to see where you used this in project.

Comment: @Larme - Still getting same issue..:( can you help me in another way `uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<netcluesvideosViewController 0x7901a780> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nameLabel.'
` .if i send you code or else? please

Comment: @EktaMakadiya-i have remove outlets ad now i am getting this error..:( `[UITableViewCell nameLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b1ba960
2015-12-03 17:21:54.490 MyFirstApp[5434:192980] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell nameLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b1ba960'
` at this line...`  cell.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`,Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to remove IBOutlet in interface builder for nameLabel, or add

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
```

to your view controller child class.

Comment: not to custom cell class, to netcluesvideosViewController